# 1D gaussian filter over non equidistant data

Tags: matlab, fortran90, gaussian, convolution

I have a data distributed in non-equidistant 1D space and I need to convolve this with a Gaussian filter,

```
gaussFilter = sqrt(6.0/pi*delta**2)*exp(-6.0*x**2 /delta**2);
```

where `delta` is a constant and `x` corresponds to space.

Can anyone hint how to perform a good integration (2nd order) as the data is not equally spaced taking care of the finite end? I intend to write the code in Fortran, but a Matlab example is also welcome.

Comment: How do you _define_ convolution with non equidistant samples?

Comment: In matlab you have `gaussfir` and `filter` functions, but they will only work for equidistant samples. If your data is non equidistant you will need to transform it to equidistant at some way. I am not aware of a way of doing that on non equidistant samples.

Comment: Transforming the data to a equidistant space will require a large number of points for correct interpolation of the data.

Comment: You may want to take a look here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/593/how-do-i-take-the-fft-of-unevenly-spaced-data

Comment: A large number of points? A cubic spline interpolation requires 3 data points (`i`, `i+1`, & `i-1`), though obviously more is better.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
function yy = smooth1D(x,y,delta)
    n = length(y);
    yy = zeros(n,1);
    for i=1:n;
        ker = sqrt(6.0/pi*delta^2)*exp(-6.0*(x-x(i)).^2 /delta^2);
        %the gaussian should be normalized (don't forget dx), but if you don't want to lose     (signal) energy, uncomment the next line
        %ker = ker/sum(ker); 
        yy(i) = y'*ker;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The kernel should be normalised then why is it commented out? What you mean losing energy? Can you please elaborate the commented stuff?

Comment: The constant befor the exp() is there so that the integral over the kernel will be 1. It means that by convolving with this kernel you are not making the signal stronger(adding energy)

Answer (score 0):

Found something which works. 
Though not sure if this is very accurate way as the integration (trapz) is of first order.

```
function [fbar] = gaussf(f,x,delta )


n = length(f);
fbar = zeros(n,1);

for i=1:n;
    kernel =  sqrt(6/(pi*delta^2))*exp(-6*((x - x(k))/delta).^2);

    kernel = kernel/trapz(x,kernel);
    fbar(i) = trapz(x,f.*kernel);
end

end
```